# ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION

Tags: axios

```
node:internal/process/promises:279
        triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
        ^
```

[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 403".] {
code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}

Comment: more information on what you are doing is needed. do a .catch(e () => { print(e)}

Comment: You forgot to share the code that triggers the error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.